# httpServlet.doPost(...) без ответа

Tags: java, http, servlet

Задача у меня следующая:
Мне приходит запрос doPost, я  его разбераю, если все хорошо, ответа ни какого не отправляем. Если есть какие то проблемы, отправляем отчет с ошибкой.
Так вот, что мне нужно положить в response, что бы от не отправлялся на клиента?

P.S. Можно конечно решить в лоб:

```
wait(n);  // n - сколько ждем отчета об ошибке.
```

но кажется мне, что это весьма костыльно.

Comment: Протокол http требует чтобы на каждый запрос был ответ. Отправьте пустую строку.

Comment: Если все хорошо, отправьте response со статусом 200 и никак не обрабатывайте его на клиенте

Comment: откуда приходит? и куда надо отправить ответ?